# Dynamics CRM - multiple plugins on same event, stage with same rank - Order of Execution?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

I came across an interview question for which I got different answers from friends and peers so I thought I'd ask here.

We generally use the plugin ranking for defining the order in which different plugins execute in order to overcome the dependency issues.

**Question**

**If an entity has multiple plugins (be it from different dlls or same dll) registered on the same event and same stage and all of them have the Rank/Order as 1 - what is the order in which they get triggered?**

Do they all execute in parallel? Does it depend on which plugin got registered first etc ? 
Please point me to any MSDN reference if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Hi please find below copied from `MSDN`,

**Execution Order:**

```
Specifies the order, also known as rank, that plug-ins are executed within a 
pipeline stage. Plug-ins registered with an order value of 1 are executed 
first, followed by plug-ins registered with an order of 2, and so on. However, 
if there is more than one plug-in in a stage with the same order value, then 
the plug-in with the earliest compilation date is called first.
```

[Using the Plug-in Registration Tool for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515(v=crm.6).aspx#bkmk_RegStep)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Believe it holds true for all CRM versions?

Comment: This is not correct now. The link is to content that is now archived. Compilation date is not a factor today.

Comment: I had two environments, one was a backup of the other. Two plugins with the same Rank in same dll. In one environment plugin A ran first, in the second environment plugin B ran first. Took a few hours to catch. version 8.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

The [SdkMessageProcessingStep.SdkMessageFilterId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/sdkmessageprocessingstep#BKMK_SdkMessageFilterId) is what manages the order in which plug-ins are executed when all other factors are equal.

Compilation date was documented years ago. IDK if it was true then, but it is not now.

Comment: isn't filter ID a GUID? Do you mean that the creation time for SdkMessageFilter decides the order?

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice (also a good interview answer), it’s not safe to rely on **CRM Product’s fallback plan** of compilation date logic. Use the execution order wisely based on our requirement.

If this CRM logic changes tomorrow or Dev team added a new plugin to the same assembly/message/stage, which has to execute on top or in between other plugins then the dependency issues rises. So design well.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for the current implementation of the Plugin Registration tool.
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/register-plug-in#general-configuration-information-fields